# How has cosmic ray flux changed over time?

Tags: cosmic-ray

Is the flux of cosmic rays now greater than it was in past eras of the Universe, less than it was in the past, or is it roughly the same? Is the answer different depending on what type of cosmic rays we are considering (lower energy, higher energy, protons, heavy nuclei, etc.?)

Comment: For the last thousands of years we have C-14 and tree rings to measure the variation, that isn't a different 'era'.

Answer (score 1):

For the last 10,000-1,000,000 years, we have cosmic ray tracks and gas products in meteorites. There has been a bit of a shift in angular distribution over the sky over the course of years-decades, but even that’s degrees, not radians or cycles.

Comment: needs supporting sources

Comment: For example, Scitech Daily's [Tree Rings Offer Insight Into Mysterious, Devastating Radiation Storms](https://scitechdaily.com/tree-rings-offer-insight-into-mysterious-devastating-radiation-storms/) links to October 26, 2022 Proceedings of the Royal Society's [Modelling cosmic radiation events in the tree-ring radiocarbon record](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.2022.0497) which goes into great detail